# How to loop through a table and call a stored proc for each row?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a temp table with 10 values like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #RequireAuth (val1 int, val2 int /*, etc...*/ )
```

How can I call another stored proc that will take in these 10 values and return me back 6 values?

```
SELECT * FROM #RequireAuth  -- Not sure how to call a SP from here?
```

I then need to take those 6 values and update a different table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some assumptions about your temp table because what you describe and what you show are different, but heres the base concept for a while loop.

```
CREATE TABLE #RequireAuth (val1 int, done bit default 0)

declare @varible int
        ,@count int


select @count =count(2) from #RequireAuth where done=0
while (@count>0) 
    BEGIn
        select top 1 @varible=val1 from #RequireAuth where done=0
        exec sp_YourProc @variable

        update R  set done=1 from #RequireAuth R where val1=@varible
        select @count =count(2) from #RequireAuth where done=0
END
```

Comment: I know this is accepted and old but how on earth does this relate to the question?